# Cloud 9, Angular and Express

Tags: angularjs, cloud9-ide

I've an angularjs project with an express 4 backend, both hosted in one cloud9-ide workspace. The node backend is running under process.env.IP (0.0.0.0) and process.env.PORT (8080). The Angular Project is living under a 'client' subfolder needs access to the backend within the workspace. The Angular App needs it's own port - right? How can I accomplish this task?

Thank you for helping me out, Günther

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what an 'angular project' means. From what I know from Angular it is more common to run Angular code on the client. This is probably why it is in a folder called 'client'.

If this is the case then express will serve the angular files to the client over the port specified. Angular will run in the browser and do all it's magic there.

If this is the case the answer to your question would be that you don't need another port and all should work as you've set it up.

Do note that Cloud9 only supports 1 port that is accessible from the outside. For most express + angular apps this is all you need.

Comment: Hi Ruben, 
Well you are right. What I am tried to do is hosting to completely disconnected projects. The angular project which lives in the 'client'-folder has access to the backend which is an express 4 projects which lives in the 'server' folder. I found no possibility to access the 'backend' from the angular project.

Well, the working solution was the following in my express app.

app.use( express.static(__dirname + './../client') );

Not really what I wanted, because I created a dependency - but it works fine. With that I only need one port accessing the backend and the frontend...Thanks!